# Servicemix 5.4 waiting for unsatisfied dependencies [[&transactionManager, &userTransaction]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, apache-servicemix, aries

I want to upgrade servicemix 4.5.2 to servicemix 5.4 I already resolve dependency issues but I come across with problem in reference to service. When my hibernate bundle is started it can't get access to services transactionManager and userTransaction. 
I tested both configuration(spring and blueprint) form https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Fuse_ESB_Enterprise/7.0/html/EIP_Transactions_Guide/XaTM-Access.html but I cant get these services.

In osgi:list I see:

```
[102] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   50] Apache Aries Transaction Manager (1.0.0)
```

In my feature.xml in my hibernate bundle configuration I have `<feature>transaction</feature>`

In log file I see :

```
2015-06-16 15:03:58,868 | INFO  | ExtenderThread-2 | OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext  | ?                                   ? | 80 - org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-context - 3.2.11.RELEASE_1 | Application Context service already unpublished
2015-06-16 15:03:58,871 | INFO  | ExtenderThread-2 | XmlBeanDefinitionReader          | ?                                   ? | 78 - org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans - 3.2.11.RELEASE_1 | Loading XML bean definitions from URL [bundle://230.0:0/META-INF/spring/beans.xml]
2015-06-16 15:03:58,905 | INFO  | ExtenderThread-2 | DependencyServiceManager         | ?                                   ? | 123 - org.springframework.osgi.extender - 1.2.1 | Adding OSGi service dependency for importer [&transactionManager] matching OSGi filter [(objectClass=javax.transaction.TransactionManager)]
2015-06-16 15:03:58,905 | INFO  | ExtenderThread-2 | DependencyServiceManager         | ?                                   ? | 123 - org.springframework.osgi.extender - 1.2.1 | Adding OSGi service dependency for importer [&userTransaction] matching OSGi filter [(objectClass=javax.transaction.UserTransaction)]
2015-06-16 15:03:58,905 | INFO  | ExtenderThread-2 | DependencyServiceManager         | ?                                   ? | 123 - org.springframework.osgi.extender - 1.2.1 | OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext(bundle=*****, config=osgibundle:/META-INF/spring/*.xml) is waiting for unsatisfied dependencies [[&transactionManager, &userTransaction]]
```

After timeout i get:

```
2015-06-16 15:08:58,911 | ERROR | Timer-1          | WaiterApplicationContextExecutor | ?                                   ? | 123 - org.springframework.osgi.extender - 1.2.1 | Unable to create application context for [******], unsatisfied dependencies: Dependency on [(objectClass=javax.transaction.TransactionManager)] (from bean [&transactionManager]), Dependency on F[(objectClass=javax.transaction.UserTransaction)] (from bean [&userTransaction])
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Application context initialization for '*******' has timed out
    at org.springframework.osgi.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.timeout(DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.java:454)[123:org.springframework.osgi.extender:1.2.1]
    at org.springframework.osgi.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.access$000(DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.java:50)[123:org.springframework.osgi.extender:1.2.1]
    at org.springframework.osgi.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor$WatchDogTask.run(DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.java:105)[123:org.springframework.osgi.extender:1.2.1]
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)[:1.7.0_21]
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)[:1.7.0_21]
2015-06-16 15:08:58,914 | ERROR | Timer-1          | ContextLoaderListener            | ?                                   ? | 123 - org.springframework.osgi.extender - 1.2.1 | Application context refresh failed (OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext(bundle=******, config=osgibundle:/META-INF/spring/*.xml))
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Application context initialization for '*******' has timed out
    at org.springframework.osgi.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.timeout(DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.java:454)[123:org.springframework.osgi.extender:1.2.1]
    at org.springframework.osgi.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.access$000(DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.java:50)[123:org.springframework.osgi.extender:1.2.1]
    at org.springframework.osgi.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor$WatchDogTask.run(DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.java:105)[123:org.springframework.osgi.extender:1.2.1]
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)[:1.7.0_21]
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)[:1.7.0_21]
```

And:

```
karaf@root>  bundle-services 102
You are about to access system bundle 102.  Do you wish to continue (yes/no): yes

org.apache.aries.transaction.manager provides:
----------------------------------
[org.osgi.service.cm.ManagedService]
[javax.transaction.TransactionManager, javax.transaction.TransactionSynchronizationRegistry, javax.transaction.UserTransaction, org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.RecoverableTransactionManager, org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by modifying the future.xml file on my hibernate bundle i added 'dependency="true"'. But still this is very strange behavior...